# Dynamic height of card

Tags: flutter

I want to be able to have a ListView within a Card and the Card's height will be decided by the ListView's height (later on I will limit the list to x items so that it won't take the entire space if there are many items.

This is an example I wrote that illustrates the "challenge", see the comment below the ListView.builder():

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyExample());

class MyExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> _data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Example')),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(
                child: new SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 440.0,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text('First card'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Card(
                child: new SizedBox(
                  child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        new MyExampleListItemWidget(_data[index]),
                    itemCount: _data.length,
                  ),
                  /// This is the one I want to be dynamic. The more items there are the more space it takes and the less space section 3 gets.
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
              ),
              new Flexible(
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text('The third section'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyExampleListItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int _index;

  MyExampleListItemWidget(this._index) : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Text('Text ' + _index.toString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a ListView if you are going to have a single child to it ?

Comment: ^because that's stackoverflow and he may not want to link everything ? :)

Comment: @Alex there are some errors in your snippets. I quite don't understand what you want because of these. Considering your code snippets are small ; you may want to provide a full end to end code (including main). So that we can directly copy-paste it and debug ourselves.

Comment: I’m sorry if the code was confusing. The list view renders the Padding/Row per item in my collection. So there could potentially be n items (n children). I’m going to render the first 3 items and add a button “show all if there are more than 3 items). If there are less than 3 items it should ideally not take the fixed height of 3.

Comment: @Darky : I will post more code in about half an hour! Thanks for the patience :)

Comment: @Darky: A little late, but the question is edited now.

Comment: I could get something working easily ; but I don't understand how your third section is supposed to work. Can you explain it ?

Comment: That's awesome! The third section is just another piece of information. You can think of the first section as an order header, the second section is the items within the order and the third section is delivery details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, late answer, but incase people are still looking for some kind of solution. There are probably many ways to do this, but building off of the OPs sample/requirements, the key is to combo it with the ListView's `shrinkWrap` property. A simplified example:

```
Card(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: _boxHeight,
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: _shrinkWrap,
      controller: _controller,
      itemCount: _myList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _myList[index];
      }),
  )
),
```

In `initState()`, you will initiate the minimum height of this `SizedBox` based on some conditions like the minimum amount of items in the list:

```
if (_myList.length <= listMinSize) {
  _boxHeight = minBoxHeight;
  _shrinkWrap = false;
}
```

Then whenever the list grows, you will check the conditions to either enable `shrinkWrap` or to set the maximum height of the box.

```
setState(() {
  listChanged();

  if (_myList.length > listMaxSize) { // lock box height, disable shrinkWrap
    _boxHeight = maxBoxHeight;
    _shrinkWrap = false;
  } else if (_myList.length > listMinSize) { // unconstrain box height, enable shrinkWrap
    _boxHeight = null;
    _shrinkWrap = true;
  } // can also check if it ever returns to listMinSize
});
```

In short, this will let your `Card/SizedBox` start off at `minBoxHeight`, grow with the `ListView` until it reaches `listMaxSize`, locking in at `maxBoxHeight`, at which point it'll have a scrolling behavior.

Now, if you wanted to make sure that the min/max boxHeights are nicely aligned with the list items, then that's a whole other issue, where you'll need to calculate the list item widget sizes and their list offsets.